# Multiple Calculations Using Case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set where I need to perform one calculation is a column is populated, if not calculate off of a different column. I'm trying to do this by using a CASE statement, however I'm not having much luck with the syntax.

```
CASE WHEN [W/O] = 'O' THEN Net * (NetShare/100) ELSE Gross * (GrossShare/100)
     WHEN [W/O] = 'W' THEN (NetShare/100)
END AS 'TEST'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: `ELSE` must be the last clause if present... like in a programming language you would `if wo = o then ... if wo = w then ... else ... end`.

Comment: If you could explain the logic you're trying to implement, that would help a lot. We're all just sort of guessing right now.

Comment: For future reference, any error you are trying to overcome should be included in its entirety in your description. Mind reading does not work - guessing might if you are lucky (and you are this time).

Comment: Thanks all, the error I'm getting is - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Comment: With regard to the logic, I want to always look at the Net fields first, however on occasion these are Null as the have not been populated with the required information yet, so if I can't do the net calculation I want to do the gross calculation. I hope that helps, thanks

Comment: What happens `WHEN [W/O] = 'W'` and `Net IS NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
(CASE WHEN [W/O] = 'O' THEN Net * (NetShare/100)
      WHEN [W/O] = 'W' THEN (NetShare/100)
      ELSE Gross * (GrossShare/100) 
 END) AS TEST
```

Comment: In the OP's example, `W` doesn't result in `Net *`.  What the `ELSE` is meant to mean though, I can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this might just be a case of that the OP's `CASE` expression is malformed. The `ELSE` is always the last expression; it can't be in the middle. Thus you need to do:

```
CASE WHEN [W/O] = 'O' THEN Net * (NetShare/100)
     WHEN [W/O] = 'W' THEN (NetShare/100)
     ELSE Gross * (GrossShare/100)
END AS TEST
```

Comment: Thanks Larnu, I didn't actually know that the Else expression is always last. I now think that I'm way off with the whole Case statement as I'm trying to calculate on Net firstly but in Net is null then calculate Gross. Maybe I need a rethink, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` expression evaluates each `WHEN`, and if nothing matches then it uses the `ELSE`, which has to come after all the `WHEN`s. Your `ELSE` is misplaced. Is this what you meant?

```
CASE 
  WHEN [W/O] = 'O' THEN Net * (NetShare/100) 
  WHEN [W/O] = 'W' THEN (NetShare/100)
  ELSE Gross * (GrossShare/100)
END AS 'TEST'
```